# Azure Application Gateway: Prevent a server from receiving new requests

Tags: azure, azure-functions, load-balancing, azure-application-gateway

I'm setting up API servers behing an `Application Gateway` on Azure. I'd like to roll out updates to each server one by one. However, before I do that, I'd like to ensure that all in-progress requests on a server are fully processed and no new requests can be received by the server. This is to prevent closing HTTP connections abruptly while the customer waits for a response.

So, suppose I have 5 servers behind a gateway and I like to update server #5. The flow I'd like to implement is as follows:

- Flag server #5 so that it does not receive any new requests
- Wait until server #5 processes all pending requests
- Update server #5
- Make it available in the app pool

Is this possible with `Application Gateway`?

Comment: You could choose a deployment time (maybe midnight and that too on weekend) when your server will have very little traffic.

Comment: Yes. I could go this route, but it means "zero downtime" is not possible. Also, in a high usage environment, I might not necessarily get little traffic especially considering idle instances are eventually killed off by the runtime on a consumption plan and whatever remains is active.

Comment: You could also use Deployment Slots in Azure Functions, but as I read over the internet, you have to upgrade your plan to Standard, Premium, or Isolated to use Deployment Slot as Consumption Plan does not support this.

Comment: AFAIK, you can use one slot per consumption plan, but it's half-baked. I frequently got 503 errors after auto-swap was enabled.